# How Display Random json_decode foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, random

I want to display randomly in `json_decode` foreach. These codes are for Laravel/php.

my table:

```
id    url        attr
1     post-1     [{"at1":"Attr-A1","at2":"Attr-A2",.....}]
```

my array (attr):

```
[{
"at1":"Attr-A1",
"at2":"Attr-A2",
"at3":"Attr-A3",
"at4":"Attr-A4",
},
{
"at1":"Attr-B1",
"at2":"Attr-B2",
"at3":"Attr-B3",
"at4":"Attr-B4",
},
{
"at1":"Attr-C1",
"at2":"Attr-C2",
"at3":"Attr-C3",
"at4":"Attr-C4",
}]
```

my controller:

```
$post = Post::where('url',$url)->first();
```

my blade

```
@foreach ( json_decode($post->attr, true) as $arr )
    <p>{{ $arr['at1'] }}</p> ,
    <p>{{ $arr['at2'] }}</p> ,
    <p>{{ $arr['at3'] }}</p> ,
    <p>{{ $arr['at4'] }}</p>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Qutput: I want the output to show `randomly`.

```
Attr-A1 , Attr-A2 , Attr-A3 , Attr-A4
Attr-C1 , Attr-C2 , Attr-C3 , Attr-C4
Attr-B1 , Attr-B4 , Attr-B3 , Attr-B4

or

Attr-C1 , Attr-C2 , Attr-C3 , Attr-C4
Attr-A1 , Attr-A2 , Attr-A3 , Attr-A4
Attr-B1 , Attr-B4 , Attr-B3 , Attr-B4
```

`shuffle` or `array_random` :  These two do not work for me.

Does `json_decode` display randomly?

Comment: JSON decode to an array, shuffle, then iterate. Not clear what you've tried so far

Comment: `json_decode` displays the values as they appear json, it would be dangerous to do it otherwise. Use code to process values before storing as json or after decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller add:

```php
$post_attr = json_decode($post->attr, true);
shuffle($post_attr);
```

Now use `$post_attr` in blade:

```php
@foreach ( $post_attr as $arr )
...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle()` works, you might have been using it in the wrong way.
First in your Controller `shuffle($post);`
Then in your blade

```
@foreach ($post as $lists)
    <p>
    @foreach ($lists as $list) 
        {{$list.', '}}
    @endforeach
    </p>
@endforeach
```